# Can I use the same port on 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.x.x

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, port, localhost

I don't quite understand how localhost relates to the private IP assigned to each machine.

If I run a server on localhost:8080, can I run something else on 192.168.x.x:8080?

More specifically if I run a python waitress server on localhost:8080 and use NGINX to reverse proxy, can I have NGINX listen on port 8080?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I run a server on localhost:8080, can I run something else on 192.168.x.x:8080?

Yes, there can be different listening sockets on the same port as long as they're bound to different local addresses (i.e. the sockets are tracked according to address:port combinations).

(But avoid mixing specific `address:port` listeners with the "any address" `0.0.0.0:port` or `[::]:port` listener. Usually that's also allowed but has stricter requirements, e.g. I think Linux disallows this if the two programs have different UIDs.)

> I don't quite understand how localhost relates to the private IP assigned to each machine.

It doesn't. The name "localhost" specifically resolves to the addresses 127.0.0.1 and [::1], nothing else. It never uses your actual LAN addresses.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` translates to `127.0.0.1`, so `localhost:8080` and `127.0.0.1:8080` are the same thing.

`192.168.x.x` is a different IP address, therefore the same port can be reused. You can run different servers on `127.0.0.1:8080` and on `192.168.0.1:8080`, and if you have more IP addresses, you can even go on with e.g.: `192.168.0.2:8080` and `192.168.0.3:8080`